# Using TextField and Button to create a message bubble in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, button, textfield, flutter-dependencies

Android Studio + Flutter

I have a Row at the bottom of the screen.

It includes TextField and Button (Add).

When there is some text in TextField and user clicks Add, I want it to appear as a Bubble inside a Container starting from the top left.

What would be the correct way to do it? I want the bubbles to accumulate like a notes app and eventually be scrollable too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Snackbar` Widget, which can be personalized heavily.

[Here's the documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBar-class.html).

**EDIT**. Since you want a permanent list of bubbles on the top, I'd suggest using a provider, so that when you click the button, the `onTap` event validates and adds the data to a list (below, `myElements`). Then, up to the top, just add a `Consumer` Widget that listens to changes to the list (it rebuilds its children every time something changes). In the following example code (I have not tested it!) I use an `Expanded` widget just for fun and I use a `ListView.builder` inside the Consumer to show the list of elements you've added, since the amount of added element could be high. Finally, I suggest using either `ListTile` or `Card` or a combination of the two, since you want something aesthetically beatiful like a bubble (you'll have to play with the settings, a little):

```
return ... (
child: Column(
  children: [
    Text("Some title..?"),
    Expanded(
      Consumer(
        builder: (ctx, myElements, _) => ListView.builder(
          itemCount: myElements.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ListTile(
            title: Text("You added ${myElements[i]}"),
            // something else...?
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Row( /* ... Text field + Button here... */),
  ],
),
// ...
```

Comment: I actually want the content to stay there so it can be observed by the user later on; Snackbar sadly won't help with that. Thanks!